# UIView autolayout constraints wrt parent

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uikit, ios-autolayout

I have a custom UIView (called myView) which has many subviews. My problem is I need to place the subviews of myView depending upon placement of myView in it's parent. So if myView is on the left side of screen, I want to place some elements on the right side of myView, and as it moves to the left beyond the center, I immediately wish to change the layout of subviews of myView. Is there an easy way to achieve this using Autolayout?

Example: Lets have a UISlider and two UIButtons in myView. If myView is on extreme left side in it's parent view, I want the UISlider to be on the left side of myView. But if myView moves to the right side in it's parent view, I want to move UISlider on the right side of myView.

Comment: Can you explain with image?

Comment: It's good for you that programmatically adding constraints is okay because that's all you have to do.

Comment: It's simple, lets have a UISlider and two UIButtons in myView. If myView is on extreme left side in it's parent view, I want the UISlider to be on the left side of myView. But if myView moves to the right side in it's parent view, I want to move UISlider on the right side of myView.@PayalManiyar

Comment: @Desdenova I am looking for those set of constraints, programatic or in storyboard doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this via code - can't do it purely with constraints.

One method:

Create a set of constraints for "left-side-layout" and another set of constraints for "right-side-layout". Then, at run-time, determine which "version" you want to use and activate only the appropriate set of constraints.

Comment: That's okay, but do I need to listen to changes in frame of myView and compute whether I am on left side or right side, or there is a better way out?

Comment: It depends on how the position / frame of `myView` is being changed. If it's only in response to you explicitly setting it via code, then you could simply call a function in `myView` to modify the constraints after you set its frame. If `myView` can move due to some event, then you could create an observer to watch for the changes, which would then call the function. Or, possibly, you could override the frame change in the view itself.